# audioPlayerEndInterruption does not work if CALLER cancels

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am using audioPlayerEndInterruption to bring back game music after an 'interruption'.
It seems to work perfectly for all scenarios tested, except: 
**if a call is received but the caller hangs up (before being answered)**, the game comes back, but the audio track does not.

As I say, all other call interruption scenarios work, the track does come back. I wonder if this is some kind of iOS bug? Has anyone heard of this problem? Seems strange.

I'm inclined to forget it for the time being, but it is annoying!
My code is like this:

```
-(void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player withFlags:(NSUInteger)flags{
    if(flags == AVAudioSessionInterruptionFlags_ShouldResume && player != nil){
        [player play];
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: Try being delegate not of AVAudioPlayer but of AVAudioSession. There similar methods. Try them to use.

Comment: Just tried that, Roman Temchenko, but got the same result. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.

I'm also experiencing this issue. It looks like a bug (at least in ios 5.1) because if all AVAudioPlayers are stopped, and openAL sounds are playing only, AVAudioSession delegate methods are called as expected (yet AVAudioPlayer's do not).

So if AVAudioPlayer is running I use a workaround: 
just add to AppDelegate::applicationDidBecomeActive call to your audioPlayerEndInterruption handler with some checks if appropriate (if sound manager exist and so on). This works for me.